# How to test overload function with repeated parameters using scalamock?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalamock

```
trait Operator{
  def addRole(index:Int,roles:String*)
  def addRole(attrIndexes:Set[Int],role:String)
}
```

How to test the first `addRole` using scalaMock?

I have tried ，all doesn't work.

```
(fakeContext.addRole(_:Int,_:String)) expects(1,Role.label)
(fakeContext.addRole _:(Int,Seq[String])=> Unit)
(fakeContext.addRole _:(Int,String) =>Unit) expects(1,Role.label)
```